# uilocalnotification is not firing at exact time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to implement `uilocalnotification` in my app. but the problem is that it is not firing at the exact time. it is firing after 30 - 40 secs from the given firing time.
Is there something I am missing or this is a common think in `UILocalNotification`.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using it for? I'm guessing that UILocalNotification isn't designed to be that accurate?

Comment: Just out of interest, how are you measuring this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UILocalNotification is designed for things that are happening far in the future so an error of 30 seconds would be OK (i.e. if I had a meeting at 15:00 then telling me at 15:00:30 wouldn't be a problem :)

If you want more accuracy than that you will need to keep your app running and use an NSTimer.

Comment: Are you sure about this. cause if my client asks me about the delay then i have to be clear about this, or my neck will be in his hand. so if you can provide me some links that say the same then ut will be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: Annoyingly, I can't find it explicitly stated anywhere but because this system is designed to use notifications from external sources, I'd assume that they don't care this much about accuracy. However, if it's that much of an issue, just schedule them 30 seconds earlier ;)

Comment: that was my original plan. I think i have to do it any way so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I have just figure this out, you can use the 
`dateByAddingTimeInterval :` method.

```
notif.fireDate = [[datePicker date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-30];
```

Comment: the problem with local notifications is that they dont fire at the exact time they are told to. If you use the above code then the local notification will trigger 1 min. before the fire time you wanted. so it might appear to fire on 3:50 but actually it will be 3:49 in ur case. that will make you feel that the notification has fired at exact time but its not. and in some cases it wont fire if the user wants to set the notification for 1 min from now.

Comment: This assumes the offset will always be 30 seconds, this is a hack, but should work assuming that 30 seconds is always the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `fireDate` by using `NSDateComponents`, in which you can set seconds for firedate. When I set it to 0 doesn't work, but it works if I set it to 1 seconds. 1 second late will be OK compared to 30-40 seconds.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay |NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond   fromDate:fireDate];
    [dateComps setSecond:1];
    [dateComps setNanosecond:00];
    NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    fireDate = newDate;
```