# How do you play a video with alpha channel using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, scenekit, swift4, arkit

I have an AR application which uses `SceneKit`, and imports a video on to scene using `AVPlayer` and thereby adding it as a child node of an `SKVideo` node.

The video is visible as it is supposed to, but the transparency in the video is not achieved.

Code as follows:

```
let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: self.sceneView.frame.width, height: self.sceneView.frame.height))
spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Triple_Tap_1", withExtension: "mp4") else {
    return
}

let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

let videoSpriteKitNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
videoSpriteKitNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)
videoSpriteKitNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
videoSpriteKitNode.yScale = -1.0
videoSpriteKitNode.play()
spriteKitScene.backgroundColor = .clear          
spriteKitScene.addChild(videoSpriteKitNode)

let background = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(2), height: CGFloat(2))
background.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene

let backgroundNode = SCNNode(geometry: background)
backgroundNode.position = position
backgroundNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]
backgroundNode.rotation.z = 0
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(backgroundNode)

// Create a transform with a translation of 0.2 meters in front of the camera.
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.2
let transform = simd_mul((self.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform)!, translation)

// Add a new anchor to the session.
let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
```

What could be the best way to implement the transparency of the `Triple_Tap_1` video in this case.
I have gone through some stack overflow questions on this topic, and found the only solution to be a KittyBoom repository that was created somewhere in 2013, using Objective C.

I'm hoping that the community can reveal a better solution for this problem. `GPUImage` library is not something I could get to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK - How to play a video with transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401517/iphone-sdk-how-to-play-a-video-with-transparency)

Comment: You could try doing the following: create a video that has a transparency mask of the footage; add it to `material.transparent.contents`; use a surface shader modifier that will be "cutting out the alpha" from `_surface.diffuse` using `_surface.transparent`. If that sounds like a somewhat reasonable solution to you, I will elaborate.

Comment: Yes please. Would help a lot.

Comment: Note that in recent versions of SceneKit using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've came up with two ways of making this possible. Both utilize surface shader modifiers. Detailed information on shader modifiers can be found in [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable).

Here's an [example project](https://github.com/2RKowski/SceneKitTransparentVideo) I've created.

---

### 1. Masking

1. You would need to create another video that represents a transparency mask. In that video black = fully opaque, white = fully transparent (or any other way you would like to represent transparency, you would just need to tinker the surface shader).
2. Create a `SKScene` with this video just like you do in the code you provided and put it into `material.transparent.contents` (the same material that you put diffuse video contents into)

   ```
   let spriteKitOpaqueScene = SKScene(...)
   let spriteKitMaskScene = SKScene(...)
   ... // creating SKVideoNodes and AVPlayers for each video etc

   let material = SCNMaterial()
   material.diffuse.contents = spriteKitOpaqueScene
   material.transparent.contents = spriteKitMaskScene

   let background = SCNPlane(...)
   background.materials = [material]
   ```
3. Add a surface shader modifier to the material. It is going to "convert" black color from the mask video (well, actually red color, since we only need one color component) into alpha.

   ```
   let surfaceShader = "_surface.transparent.a = 1 - _surface.transparent.r;"
   material.shaderModifiers = [ .surface: surfaceShader ]
   ```

That's it! Now the white color on the masking video is going to be transparent on the plane.

**However** you would have to take extra care of syncronizing these two videos since `AVPlayer`s will probably get out of sync. Sadly I didn't have time to address that in my example project (yet, I will get back to it when I have time). Look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550032/two-avplayer-videos-out-of-sync-swift) for a possible solution.

**Pros:**

- No artifacts (if syncronized)
- Precise

**Cons:**

- Requires two videos instead of one
- Requires synchronisation of the `AVPlayer`s

---

### 2. Chroma keying

1. You would need a video that has a vibrant color as a background that would represent parts that should be transparent. Usually green or magenta are used.
2. Create a `SKScene` for this video like you normally would and put it into `material.diffuse.contents`.
3. Add a chroma key surface shader modifier which will cut out the color of your choice and make these areas transparent. I've lent this [shader from GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.m) and I don't really know how it actually works. But it seems to be explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16911019/6192057).

   ```
    let surfaceShader =
   """
   uniform vec3 c_colorToReplace = vec3(0, 1, 0);
   uniform float c_thresholdSensitivity = 0.05;
   uniform float c_smoothing = 0.0;

   #pragma transparent
   #pragma body

   vec3 textureColor = _surface.diffuse.rgb;

   float maskY = 0.2989 * c_colorToReplace.r + 0.5866 * c_colorToReplace.g + 0.1145 * c_colorToReplace.b;
   float maskCr = 0.7132 * (c_colorToReplace.r - maskY);
   float maskCb = 0.5647 * (c_colorToReplace.b - maskY);

   float Y = 0.2989 * textureColor.r + 0.5866 * textureColor.g + 0.1145 * textureColor.b;
   float Cr = 0.7132 * (textureColor.r - Y);
   float Cb = 0.5647 * (textureColor.b - Y);

   float blendValue = smoothstep(c_thresholdSensitivity, c_thresholdSensitivity + c_smoothing, distance(vec2(Cr, Cb), vec2(maskCr, maskCb)));

   float a = blendValue;
   _surface.transparent.a = a;
   """

   shaderModifiers = [ .surface: surfaceShader ]
   ```

   To set uniforms use `setValue(:forKey:)` method.

   ```
   let vector = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0) // represents float RGB components
   setValue(vector, forKey: "c_colorToReplace")
   setValue(0.3 as Float, forKey: "c_smoothing")
   setValue(0.1 as Float, forKey: "c_thresholdSensitivity")
   ```

   The `as Float` part is important, otherwise Swift is going to cast the value as `Double` and shader will not be able to use it.

   But to get a precise masking from this you would have to really tinker with the `c_smoothing` and `c_thresholdSensitivity` uniforms. In my example project I ended up having a little green rim around the shape, but maybe I just didn't use the right values.

**Pros:**

- only one video required
- simple setup

**Cons:**

- possible artifacts (green rim around the border)

Comment: I will try this out.

Comment: You can read more about problems with the ChromaKey approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17307035/763355

Comment: Hey Lësha, I downloaded your example project and used your video and the ChromaKeyMaterial and VideoContent classes in my own project and that works fine. But when I use my own video the video is totally invisible. Can you help me fix this problem? I have the same green background you are using in the chromakeyfootage.mp4 video.

Comment: @KNV does the video work without using ChromaKeyMaterial (just plain SCNMaterial with VideoContent as diffuse contents)?

Comment: @LëshaTurkowski No, your video does also not work without the ChromaKeyMaterial.

Comment: just checking, did you have any idea how to use chroma with RealityKit? I am using this library to remove the chroma key color from the video and it works well. But maybe there are easier ways? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70110548/9497800