# UIImage obtaining CVPixelBuffer Removes Alpha

Tags: ios, swift, alpha, cgcontext, cvpixelbuffer

The function below takes in an `UIImage` and returns a `CVPixelBuffer` from the `UIImage` but it removes the alpha channel.

```
class func pixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool, size: CGSize) -> CVPixelBuffer {

        var pixelBufferOut: CVPixelBuffer?

        let status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBufferOut)
        if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
            fatalError("CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer() failed")
        }

        let pixelBuffer = pixelBufferOut!

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])

        let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        let horizontalRatio = size.width / image.size.width
        let verticalRatio = size.height / image.size.height
        //aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
        let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit

        let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width * aspectRatio, height: image.size.height * aspectRatio)

        let x = newSize.width < size.width ? (size.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
        let y = newSize.height < size.height ? (size.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

        context!.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))


        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])

        return pixelBuffer
    }
```

1. I know the initial image has some pixels with a specific `alpha = 0` because if I do `po image.pixelColor(atLocation: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))` it prints

> Optional
>     - some : UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0

but the resulting image has a black background.

I also tried using `CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue` but that results in the image being blue, so I assume the `RGBA` to `ARGB` are getting swapped. But, ironically, that would mean that B in `ARGB` is 255 which would indicate that in `RGBA` that A would be 255, which it should be 0.

How can I correctly get the `UIImage` alpha to translate into the `CVPixelBuffer` when using `CGContext`?

**Edit 1:**

Here is my code for my `pixelBufferPool`.

```
func createPixelBufferAdaptor() {
            let pixelFormatRGBA = kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA //Fails
            let pixelFormatARGB = kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB //Works
            let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
                kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: pixelFormatARGB),
                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.width)),
                kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.height))
            ]
            pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
                                                                      sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)
        }
```

It only works when I use `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB`. What I mean by work is that when I attempt to use the bufferpool

```
let status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBufferOut)
        if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
            fatalError("CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer() failed")
        }
```

this fails if I use the `RGBA` version but works if I use the `ARGB` version.

Comment: Please attach the code how do you create `pixelBufferPool`. Are you passing there in the attributes the key `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` as `kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA`?

Comment: I was not. I was using `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB which makes sense why my `A` would be 255, but doesn't make sense in that I did have blue in my picture and the `B` should be a 0. Nonetheless, I attempted to switch to `RGBA` to test out my theory and it would crash. The `Edit 1` above describes what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, sadly, my scope for this topic was too narrow (ironic since most questions are considered too broad).

I was trying to create a video from a `AVCaptureSession` alongside `AVAssetWriter` and some of the images had a Depth Map that I would then produce to turn some of the pixels to a clear color. Well, with some research I found out that for images and displaying them, the alpha channel is maintained. But, for videos, this is impossible.

[How do you play a video with alpha channel using AVFoundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225828/how-do-you-play-a-video-with-alpha-channel-using-avfoundation)
https://andreygordeev.com/2017/07/01/video-with-transparent-background-ios/
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3205
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3cw4le/is_it_possible_to_play_a_video_with_an_alpha/

Anywho, my next goal is to do a `ChromaKey` as described by some of the answers - either that or a masking from the depth map applied to my features.