# local notification not working at the exact time as selected from datepicker but after a few seconds in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

`enter code here`I'm new in swift 3.currently i'm working to make a local notification on setting a note and giving a notification time using date picker.my problem is notification is getting fired only after a few seconds(say sometimes 5sec,34sec,18 sec etc) after the notification firedate.

i got the code from 
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

thank you

Comment: Please post some code about what you have tried till now so if there is any error we can guide you for your issue

Comment: code is same in the link i given above... http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Comment: Links may get broke with some time span and readers will not able to see what you have done and how you have implemented so I just give comment to put some code related to issue you are asking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064808/3066450) that says UILocalNotification fire time isn't that accurate. I was also going through Apple's documentation on `Timer` and found this regarding timer tolerance

> The system reserves the right to apply a small amount of tolerance to
>   certain timers regardless of the value of the tolerance property.

Since the scheduled notification will be using a timer behind the scenes, the system must be applying a small tolerance to improve power saving. If you want to read more about timer tolerance read this [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer) on timer.